# Comma(,) specified in file name makes curl processor fail to send a request

Tags: java, rest, curl, multipart

I have a Curl processor class which is used to send requests and get response as a plain string.

It worked like a charm, however recently I've encountered a problem. The problem has to do with sending multipart data. So, if there's a comma (perphaps other special character) specified in multipart body, it doesn't even send any request.

Here's what I mean (main method below)

```
public static String buildCurlProcessBuilderExecuteAndGetResponse(String httpMethod, String URL, List<String> headers, List<String> body, boolean includeResponseHeaders) throws IOException 
{
        List<String> finalCommands = new ArrayList<String>();

        finalCommands.add("/usr/local/bin/curl");
        finalCommands.add("-s");
        finalCommands.add("-k");

        if (includeResponseHeaders) 
        {
            finalCommands.add("-i");
        }

        finalCommands.add("-X");
        finalCommands.add(httpMethod);

        finalCommands.add(URL);

        if (headers != null) 
        {
            finalCommands.addAll(headers);
        }

        if (body != null) 
        {
            finalCommands.addAll(body);
        }

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(finalCommands);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);       
        Process p = pb.start();
        return getResponseAsString(p.getInputStream());
}
```

I add multipart body like so:

```
public static List<String> addMultipartBodyToCurlRequest(Map<String, String> mapOfheadersToAdd) 
{
        Iterator<Entry<String, String>> multipartBodyIt = mapOfheadersToAdd.entrySet().iterator();
        List<String> bodyCommand = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (multipartBodyIt.hasNext())
        {       
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) multipartBodyIt.next();

            bodyCommand.add(CURL_MULTIPART_BODY_IDENTIFIER); // "-F";
            bodyCommand.add((String) pair.getKey() + "=" + (String) pair.getValue());
        }

        return bodyCommand;
}
```

I put the following properties to the body:

```
generatedBody.put("entityId", entityId);
generatedBody.put("SystemFolderID", systemFolderId);
generatedBody.put("resumableTotalSize", fileSize);
generatedBody.put("resumableFilename", fileName);
generatedBody.put("resumableRelativePath", fileName);
generatedBody.put("resumableIdentifier", fileUUID);
generatedBody.put("entityName", entityName);
generatedBody.put("resumableType", resumableType);
generatedBody.put("resumableTotalChunks", totalChunksSize);
```

And also

```
generatedBody.put("resumableChunkNumber", String.valueOf(i + 1));
generatedBody.put("resumableChunkSize", String.valueOf(chunkByteArray.length));
generatedBody.put("resumableCurrentChunkSize", String.valueOf(chunkByteArray.length));
generatedBody.put("file", "@" + currentChunk.getAbsolutePath() + ";" + "filename=" + fileName);
```

Then I call the method:

```
List<String> fileBody = CURLRequestProcessor.addMultipartBodyToCurlRequest(generatedBody);
```

And finally call

```
CURLRequestProcessor.buildCurlProcessBuilderExecuteAndGetResponse("POST", finalURL, generatedHeaders, fileBody, false)
```

But I don't get printed anything... It seems like one simple comma in the name of the file screwed everything up... It's used in the `resumableFilename`, `resumableRelativePath` and `file` parts.

Without comma in the name everything works. Is there a way to escape or do anything?

Btw, it's run on Ubuntu.

Almost forgot, **PLEASE DON'T ASK ME WHY I'M USING CURL OVER any other HTTP client**. I have to due to TLS

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be simple yet peculiar.

The problem had to do with this line:

```
generatedBody.put("file", "@" + currentChunk.getAbsolutePath() + ";" + "filename=" + fileName);
```

I changed it to:

```
generatedBody.put("file", "@" + currentChunk.getAbsolutePath());
```

Since I send the name of the file in 2 additional body parts called `resumableFilename` and `resumableRelativePath`, so specifying `filename` is redundant. In the latter comma screws up, while with these two parts comma doesn't matter

I wonder what if didn't have these though...

Answer (score 0):

HTTP headers support quoted strings that contain special characters.  Try putting the values in quotes.

```
generatedBody.put("resumableRelativePath", "\"" + fileName + "\"");
```

If your file name contains a `"` character, you can escape it with a single backslash within the quoted string.

Comment: What is "\n"" for?

Comment: @Rus9Mus9 fixed now